# Appium, Java & Testng - find the reason for a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, appium, driver

I am getting a `NullPointerException` before Appium and the emulator launch. So trying to debug by having `sysout` lines in the code is not helping at all. 
If anyone has some advice please send through as I am going crazy!

My dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-beta3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

My Hooks class:

```
package MA.test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Hooks {

    public AppiumDriver driver;
    public AppiumDriverLocalService service;

    @Parameters({"platformVersion", "emulatorNumber", "deviceName", "port"})
    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void startAppiumServer(String platformVersion, String emulatorNumber, String deviceName, String port) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("\n ABC");
        service = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .usingPort(Integer.valueOf(port))
                .build();
        service.start();
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, platformVersion);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, emulatorNumber);
        caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.AVD, deviceName);
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPLICATION_NAME, "Name");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.14.0");
        caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "activity");
        caps.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "package");
        caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");

        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:" + port + "/wd/hub"), caps);

        System.out.println("\n Appium server: " + service.getUrl());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void teardown() {
        service.stop();
        driver.quit();
        driver.closeApp();
        System.out.println("\n Test quit");
    }
}
```

My TestRunner class:

```
package MA.steps;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber-reports"}
        , monochrome = true
        , features = "src/test/java/feature"
        , tags = "@Login"
)

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

My testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Android Parallel Execution" parallel="tests" thread-count="2" verbose="7">
    <test name="Device1">
        <parameter name="platformVersion" value="9.0"/>
        <parameter name="emulatorNumber" value="emulator-5554"/>
        <parameter name="deviceName" value="Android9_Nexus"/>
        <parameter name="port" value="4723"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="MA.steps.TestRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And I am receiving the following error:

> *java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at screens.myAccountOverviewScreen.logoutAccount(myAccountOverviewScreen.java:104)*

Which points to the following line of code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This ^ is the first time `driver` is called in my tests, but what baffles me is that it is throwing a `nullpointerexception` without even launching appium, or starting the emulator.

Comment: Can you please try to init your driver like the following?         driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:" + port + "/wd/hub"), caps);

Comment: Could You please provide implementation of ```myAccountOverviewScreen.java```?  Thankful in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your test code.

You created a suite xml file to include only your `TestRunner` class. But the entire of the appium instantiation logic is stuck in the `Hooks` class which does it via the TestNG configuration annotation `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest`. But this class is neither included in your suite, nor your test class (`TestRunner`) extends it. So your configurations aren't getting invoked leading to a null value for your `AppiumDriver` object.

To fix the problem, you can do one of the following:

1. Edit your suite xml file and include `Hooks` class also in it. **(or)**
2. Build a TestNG listener which implements `IInvokedMethodListener` and move your driver instantiation into its `beforeInvocation`

Comment: Thank you for this advice! I included Hooks in my xml file, it solved the problem of the simulator not being instantiated. The driver however is still causing issues, as my app loads on the emulators, but still throws a nullpointerexception on the first piece of code which calls the driver implicit wait

Comment: Would you happen to know of a reason why this happens? The driver is fine until it reaches the test code, where it then turns to null.